# Kubuntu 20.04 -- Skype for Linux needs key ring password every system restart

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, skype, keyrings

For the past few months, Skype for Linux (kept up to date via its own repository/PPA) has asked for my password to access my keyring the first time it's opened after each cold start or reboot.

Nothing else is doing this, and I seem to recall it started after a major Skype update (though it's been long enough I'm not really certain of that).

It's not a *huge* issue, but it would be more convenient not to have to supply this again every time I have to reboot my computer (say, after a kernel update, or a software freeze).

I've searched a bit, but didn't find anything recent enough to be applicable (older versions of both Ubuntu and Skype).

How do I get Skype to remember its keyring access?

Edit: more than a year later, it still does this, and nothing suggested in comments led to any additional breakthroughs.

Comment: Does your login use a password (which open a keyring too)?  Fingerprint login doesn't, so cannot open a keyring.  Is the Skype keyring the same one that login/password opens?  Then again, I hear Microsoft is going to kill Skype, so maybe this is part of the migration plan -- make it more inconvenient to use.

Comment: Haven't heard of MS killing Skype.  I login to Kubuntu with a password, hence why no other software needs to ask for it.  Skype having a separate keyring would cause this, but I don't know how to determine that or how to fix it if it does.

Comment: One can see what keyrings exist by using the `seahorse` app, aka "Passwords and Keys".  On some installs, I've ended up with more than one keyring for unknown reasons, which was an endless source of irritation and a non-trivial thing to figure out the fix. If having 2 keyrings turns out to be the issue, I can look up what I did to fix it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Hmm.  I think I installed that last time I was poking at this, but got nowhere with a fix from Ubuntu 17.x (Skype has made *major* changes since 2017).